# ReactiveX Observable from NodeJS Express 'post'

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming

Is it possible to create an ReactiveX Observable from:

```
app = express();
app.post('/path', function() {...})
```

?

I mean, there exists a way to create an observable `fromEvent` in which I already used for lots of events that were registered using `object.on('eventName', function(){})` but the post from express is not exactly like that.

Answer (score 11):

#### Rx-ify express all the way?

The added complexity of trying to convert the callback-style implementation of routing in express towards Rx makes me conclude that this is not the way forward. This is because express does not know Rx thus has no notion of subscription lifetime and multiple event emissions.

The answer of martin is a proof-of-concept in which you can see the above issues clearly. It would mean that for every route you would need to create a separate `Subject` or `share()` one subject and then make a lot of filters for every route to separate implementations. Which is *redundant* because express has already routed your request to the correct handler.

#### Combine Rx world with express callbacks

If you want to have the benefits of Expressjs routes combined with RxJs I would separate the routing logic and keep that in express callbacks and the actual implementation use that as Rx combined with a `.toPromise()` to activate it:

```
app.post('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
  return getUserById(req.params.id)
    .toPromise()/* return the Rx stream as promise to express so it traces its lifecycle */
    .then(
      user => res.send(user),
      err => res.status(500).send(err.message)
    );
});    

function getUserById(id) {
  // stub implementation
  return Rx.Observable.of({ id, name: 'username' }) 
    .delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think the easiest way is using a `Subject` to reemit events from `express`.

```
var express = require('express');
var Rx = require('rxjs');
var app = express();

let subject = new Rx.Subject();

app.get('/', (req, res) => subject.next([req, res]));

subject
  .do(a => console.log('123345'))
  .subscribe(args => {
    let [req, res] = args;
    res.send('Hello World!');
  });

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

The main difference is that you need to wrap `[req, res]` as an array because you want to pass both to `subject.next(...)`. This can be later unpacked with `let [req, res] = args;`.

Unfortunately, you can't use `Observable.bindCallback` because it takes just a single response from the wrapped function and then completes which is now what you want in this scenario.

Comment: why let and not var?

Comment: also I'm getting that subject.next is not a function

Comment: It should be 'onNext'

Comment: No, in RxJS 5 the method is called just `next()`. Names such as `onNext()` were used in the older RxJS 4.